# Phone is unable to connect to any Wi-Fi network

Tags: wifi, lumia-925

My Lumia 925 is able to recognize all Wi-Fi networks in the vicinity when I switch on the Wi-Fi. However, it is not able to connect to any network when I try. it says: "Can't connect to this Wi-Fi network now, try again later". It has been doing this for two weeks now. For a year my phone was able to connect to my home Wi-Fi and other Wi-Fi networks without any issues. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried a hard reset since upgrading the phone?

Answer (score 1):

I also experience the same issue on  my Lumia 930 which I bought in April 2015.

Turning the WiFi off and on solves the issue.

Hopefully when we upgrade to the latest OS this issue will be eliminated.

Had a Lumia 520 before this one and I was not experiencing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem from time to time with my Lumia 920 and then later with my 930. Turning wifi off and on doesn't seem to fix it.

To solve this, usually I found that powering off and then starting again would allow connection.

Annoying, yes. I don't know why, but it may be something in one of the OS upgrades. Did you upgrade your Windows 8.1 OS soon before these issues started? Hopefully a future OS upgrade will eliminate this problem.

Comment: Yes I did upgrade it to 8.1 few months back.. but even after the upgrade the wifi connections happened fine.. I started seeing the issue only since few weeks and I can't remember making any change in my phone that may have caused this issue. I tried restarting my phone a couple of times but still couldn't connect to my home wifi.. please suggest if there is a latest upgrade that can resolve this issue..

Comment: Here's a few people who had the same issue along with some suggestions: http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Lumia/Lumia-925-Wifi-issue/td-p/2266691

Answer (score 0):

Same here sees wifi but will not connect trying hard power down now and see if it comes up afterwards.

Powered down

Wait to type this entry

Powering up

YES it's connected

WARNING - I have had earlier temp drop outs so if it happens to you suggest you do as above before it becomes a firm problem